# Finding the probability that the rays will hit the vertices

Tags: probability, probability-theory

While playing with my laser, a question came in my mind.

Suppose we are in a perfect cubical room with the four walls being a perfect reflector($100$% efficiency) of light. Now a laser is fixed at one of the vertices and it is switched on and all the Rays are considered to remain in a horizontal plane.

**What is the probability that it will hit the vertices of the wall being in the same horizontal plane all the time** ?

I have no idea what to do since this question was just self made.

Comment: what have you thought of so far?

Comment: "at any random angle" means angle from where? Does it mean the ray starts at a corner of the cube and then goes in any possible direction? If so why would it stay in a single horizontal plane?